# Ckeditor для WebView Javafx

Tags: javafx, webview, ckeditor

Понадобилось такое решение, когда в сцену `JavaFX` мне необходимо добавить `WebView` с `HTML` редактором, поэтому решил взять `CKEdit5`, так как `HTMLEdit` не подошел.
Структура проекта:

[image: структура]

Создан `html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="../js/ckeditor/build/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="editor"></div>
  <script>
    ClassicEditor
      .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Контроллер:

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    try {
        URL urleditor = TemplateCkeEditorController.class.getResource("/html/cke-editor.html");
        WebEngine engine = webview.getEngine();
        engine.load(urleditor.toExternalForm());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, e.getMessage()).showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Однако при просмотре из проекта с помощью IDE я вижу редактор, а при запуске приложения на сцене пусто. В какую сторону посмотреть? Я что то делаю неправильно для загрузки `HTML` из контроллера? Или проблема в `WebView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема исчезла после:

```
mvn compile
```

Моя невнимательность.